# Cytoscape for coloring the nodes in the network

Tags: r, proteins, protein-protein-interaction, cytoscape

I need to color different categories of the proteins in the interaction network automatically. Is there any way to color each category with a different color in cytoscape? or R?

My input is 2 column interaction protein ID. I have different categories of proteins in CSV format separately only with protein ID.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In protein -protein interaction network, I need to color the proteins of the different categories with different colors. I have four categories of proteins.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999877/correctly-color-vertices-in-r-igraph, https://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Styles.html